# Running a loop continuously using camel route on jboss fuse

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse

Need to read data from a socket(),parse and write to data base using ibatis.This has to be done continuously.Not sure how to run this process continously. Thought of using camel loop .But it looks like we need to mention the loop count.

```xml
<route id="vts-data">
    <from uri="timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1" />
    <doTry>
        <loop>
            <to uri="bean:vtsProcessor?method=extractLocations" />
            <log message="Details List is  : ${body}" />
        </loop>
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${body.size} == 0</simple>
                <log message="List is null ${body}" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <to uri="mybatisPromis:insertLocationData?statementType=SelectList" />
                <log message="Details List is : ${body}" />
                <choice>
                    <when>
                        <simple>${body.size} == 0</simple>
                        <log message="Details List is null : ${body}" />
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                        <log message="Details List is  : ${body}" />
                    </otherwise>
                </choice>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
        <doCatch>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
        </doCatch>
        <doFinally>
            <to uri="log:body" />
        </doFinally>
    </doTry>
</route>
```

I am new to camel and fuse. Thought of using worker thread to run the process continuously but not luck. Need some pointers to do in optimized approach.

Answer (score 0):

The camel route provides the "always running process". Its just a matter of arranging the components and EIP's to meet your requirement.

1. The recommended approach would be to read from the socket in the "from"
2. If not #1, you should look at using a pollingConsumer pattern.. timer runs.. polls the socket endpoint.. then persist into ibatis

ref: http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html